# Gage or Gauge? Which is correct in the aviation industry?

Tags: terminology

Gage or Gauge?

Some official aviation sources seem to use the spelling "gage" whether referencing cockpit instruments or aircraft maintenance tooling.

However, more broad English sources note that "gage" is either interchangeable with "guage," or flat out incorrect.

Is either spelling technically correct, or only one?

Do the different spellings hold different meanings or connotations in aviation?

Are there official examples that could make the argument "gage" could be correct in specific circumstances (patents, manuals, industry standards, trademarks)?

Is there a history in early aviation using "gage" that has been carried over unofficially to today (like how older aircraft operating today may have mph on their airspeed indicator)?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: You may get a better response on english.SE. Identifying the correct spelling of a word isn't very aviation-related, IMO, even if the word in question is.

Comment: "I see gage used rampantly in aviation" I'd be interested to know where.

Comment: *"Some official aviation sources"* Which ones? Please give a few *specific* examples.

Comment: I think this should be reopened.  This is not unlike asking is it more prevalent to say "aeroplane" or "airplane".  Some things aren't wrong or right.  It could be a nationality issue like 'aluminum' vs. 'aluminium', but since the question was voted to close, now none of us who don't know will learn the answer.

Comment: @RyanMortensen The question might have merit, but it'd probably be a lot easier to answer if OP just provides a few examples where (in this case) "gage" is used in aviation. As it stands, I think this is asking for us to guess at a little too much.

Comment: OP: the edit has not helped you, as now you're asking too many questions all at once. And this is still a better fit for [english.se]

Answer (score 2):

Gauge is correct. As in Oil temperature gauge, Fuel Pressure gauge, Fuel Level gauge, Cylinder Head Temperature gauge, Exhaust Gas Temperature gauge, etc.

Anyone use gage is misspelling the word.  Same with Hangar. (Not hanger)

Comment: To clarify, both "gage" and "hanger" are real words, but not as likely to be used in aviation (especially "gage")

Comment: @fooot I don't know; I might appreciate some kind of hanger in the cockpit of an airliner, to hang my coat on; especially during the winter months...

Comment: Yes, but not for parking your airplane in so you can work on the gauges.